# WP Как понять какими хуками собирается страница?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть ли какие-то плагины, которыей способны визуально для тестов показать какие хуки подключают стороние плагины что б сгенерировать, тот или иной контент ? Я читал про [doing_filter()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/doing_filter)
Но это если мы знаем, что за что отвечает, а как быть если эта информация неизвесна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ещё нашел, [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) этот помощнее будет и отображение приятнее. Если кто-то тоже будет искать.

Answer (score 2):

> Есть ли какие-то плагины, которыей способны визуально для тестов
> показать какие хуки подключают стороние плагины

И не один. Например https://wordpress.org/plugins/another-show-hooks/